# Column 'City.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried the following SQL Query and it is giving the error stated below:

```
Select TOP 1 CITY,MAX(LEN(CITY)) 
from STATION 
ORDER BY CITY ASC
```

Error

> Column 'STATION.CITY' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Table :

```
CREATE TABLE City (
  ID Integer NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  Name VARCHAR (255),
  CountryCode VARCHAR (255),
  District VARCHAR (255),
  PopulationofCity Integer
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are looking for the longest city name.

Then order by descending length

```
SELECT TOP 1 CITY, LEN(CITY)
FROM STATION
GROUP BY CITY
ORDER BY LEN(CITY) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to city in group by

```
 Select TOP 1 CITY,MAX(LEN(CITY)) 
 from STATION group by CITY
 ORDER BY CITY ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing group by clause

```
Select TOP 1 CITY,MAX(LEN(CITY)) from STATION 
group by city
ORDER BY CITY ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT CITY,LEN(CITY) AS CITYLENGTH FROM STATION ) A ORDER BY A.CITYLENGTH DESC
```